# Why did the Black Pearl not change?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

Near the end of the movie, the Trident is broken, releasing all the curses of the sea.

The effect of this is pretty clear; we can see Salazar & crew returned to life and we later also spot the *Flying Dutchman*, which has also been restored to its former glory.

However, the *Black Pearl* remains exactly the same, even though it was originally raised from the depths by Davy Jones and was actually a different ship before then.

**Is there any specific reason that the *Black Pearl* did not change back to its previous form?**

From what I remember it was always considered to be a cursed ship, and the *Flying Dutchman* and its crew were reverted to their normal forms; I would expect the *Black Pearl* to also be restored.

Answer (score 8):

Though it was raised from depth by Davy Jones, it wasn't cursed and there is no particular explanation if it was cursed. You might have mixed plots with *Curse of the Black Pearl*. In that movie, there was curse on the pirates, not on the ship.

In POTC universe, as [explained on this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Pearl), Black Pearl was originally named as Wicked Wench and was destroyed by Cutler Beckett. That's when Jack made a deal with Davy Jones. Though the ship was raised from the depth of sea by Davy Jones, it was redesigned by Jack. **There was no curse on this ship, so there is no reason why it should have been restored back to its former glory.**

> The Wicked Wench turned into an inferno, then sank, taking Jack with her. But, while dying, the resourceful Sparrow called upon Davy Jones, and struck a bargain with him...his soul and one hundred years serving aboard the Flying Dutchman in return for a continued human existence of thirteen years as captain, plus saving the Wicked Wench and transforming her into the fastest, most dangerous pirate ship sailing the seven seas. Jack christened his resurrected Wench, now a black vessel with an angel figurehead, The Black Pearl.

In case of Salazar and his crew, there was curse on them which was broken after Trident of Poseidon was destroyed.

In case of [The Flying Dutchman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Dutchman_(Pirates_of_the_Caribbean)), there was curse on Davy Jones, that shifted later on Will Turner when he became the captain, and his crew in Pirates of the Caribbean universe. When the curse broke, they could no longer stay alive underwater, therefore that ship was needed to be above water.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the canon of Pirates of the Caribbean was disrupted by Dead Men Tell No Tales. In the movie, the Wicked Wench is shown to be a pirate vessel and the compass to not initially in Jack's possession. This runs counter to the canon to this point, where the Wench was an EITC ship under Jack's command.

Comment: Although I think this is the best answer, we're going to get for a while, I think that there is a difference between the purpose of TFD (to ferry the souls), which is what made Davy Jones "cursed" (he, his crew, and the ship became anthropomorphic sea creatures) vs "The Dutchman must always have a Captain" mantra, as Davy Jones seems to exist as he was before death in the post credit scene of the film, implying some sort of reset.

Comment: Similarly though, upon rechristening, The Black Pearl became the fastest ship, meaning that there is magic involved, so I do think the Q is interesting in that TFD doesn't look as magical (although it could still very well be, given it's purpose) and that the Black Pearl seems like it's still a ghost ship. But as mentioned in previous comment, Davy Jones seems to be back, so it feels like there is something we are missing. Whether it's not all magic is a curse being a simple solution or if there is some other catch 22 remains to be seen.

Comment: Which POTC film is this, btw? I've only seen up to the third one. I'm not a stickler about spoilers either.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Dead Man Tell No Tales or POTC:5 :)

Comment: That explains it. Hadn’t seen that one

Answer (score -3):

well, the black plearl wasn't cursed. The crew were. Jones brought it back, but with age, the hull turned black.
And that's my awnser

Comment: Can you back this up with references to the movies? This currently reads just like your opinion.

Comment: This reiterates points already made in [A J 9's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/74932/62673), 3 years ago, and does not add any new information.